# jsp to convert JsonArray elements

Tags: jsp, liferay, jspdf-autotable

I am creating my array as such that has a key value (Name and Email) like this and with a loop populating as below:

```
for(x y : model) {
             
               obj_JSONObject1.append(x.getName(), x.getValue()); 
              
        }
            jsonArray.put(obj_JSONObject1);
```

My Array looks like this:

```
[
  {
"Email": [
      "email1@email.com",
      "abc@liferay.com"
    ],
    "Name": [
      "name1",
      "name2"
    ]
}
]
```

However I am having problem displaying them in an html table from my jsp. I tried:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${userList.length() -1}" var="i">
<tr>
     <td>${userList.getJSONObject(i).get("Name")}
      </td>
      <td>${userList.getJSONObject(i).get("Email")}
     </td>
    
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The table is created as :
Name                                 Email
["name1","name2"]   ["email1@email.com","abc@liferay.com"]

Can someone tell me how to display the records in tabular format(the values should be on each rows and not sidewide? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need two nested `c:forEach` loops here, one to iterate over the outer `userList` array and the other to iterate over the inner `Name` and `Email` arrays.

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${userList.length() - 1}" var="i">
    
    <c:set var="names" value='${userList.getJSONObject(i).get("Name")}' />
    <c:set var="emails" value='${userList.getJSONObject(i).get("Email")}' />

    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${names.length() - 1}" var="j">
    <tr>
        <td>${names.getString(j)}</td>
        <td>${emails.getString(j)}</td> 
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
```

<sup>*The example assumes that the `Name` and `Email` arrays will always contain the same number of items. If not, some kind of error handling would need to be put in place.*</sup>

Comment: Thank you, @Ravi, I got an initial error saying  The class 'org.json.JSONArray' does not have the property 'length'. so added 'lenth()' on inner for each, however now getting this error:   The class 'org.json.JSONArray' does not have the property '0'.  Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also please note, I tried item iterator, and got this error: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;  Please note, I am running the code from view.jsp that is part of Liferay framework/cms.  Thank you

Comment: @Aftab Ah, got it. I incorrectly presumed the inner instances would be a Java array, but they are JSONArrays. Let me update my answer. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Aftab Please test with the updated code now.